# django dynamic custom queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a table to store view events, that is, if a user views an entity, a record will be stored into that table. This table is represented by a model that has a generic relation, that is, it can be related to any other model.

I have defined a mixin `ViewTracked` that should be extended by any model that can be tracked (i.e. `class SomeModel(ViewTracked)`).

I want to have a custom method for queryset of `objects` manager called `custom_method` for example. I know that I can define a custom `Manager` and override the `objects` manager with it easily, but the problem is that the tracked model can already have a custom manager that has his own custom queryset, so I can't simply override it and lose the custom queryset that it has.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find a proper way of doing this, so I tried to add a metaclass to override the manager's `get_queryset` and add my custom method to it, but for some reason, when I call `SomeModel.objects` it always returns `None`.

Here's what I tried:

```py
# Meta class
class ViewTrackedMeta(ModelBase):
    def __new__(mcs, class_name, base_classes, attributes_dict):
        # let ModelBase do its magic
        new_class = super().__new__(mcs, class_name, base_classes, attributes_dict)
        if hasattr(new_class, 'objects'):
            objects_manager = new_class.objects
            if isinstance(objects_manager, Manager):
                queryset = objects_manager.get_queryset()

                def custom_method(queryset):
                    return queryset.filter(...)

                def get_extended_queryset(manager):
                    queryset.custom_method = types.MethodType(custom_method, queryset)
                objects_manager.get_queryset = types.MethodType(get_extended_queryset, objects_manager)
        return new_class

# Mixin
class ViewTracked(Model, metaclass=ViewTrackedMeta):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    ...

# Models
class SomeModel(ViewTracked):
    objects = CustomManager()


class SomeOtherModel(ViewTracked):
    ... # default django objects manager


class SomeOtherModel(ViewTracked):
    objects = OtherCustomManager()
```

Is there any other way I can achieve what I want? Why `SomeModel.objects` is always returning `None`?

Comment: Did you try instantiating the manager classes? `objects = CustomManager()`

Comment: Sorry it's a typo in the question, in my real code I'm already instantiating them. I edited the code.

Answer (score 0):

Other than instaniating your manager classes, you should be using `from_queryset`. Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset).

```
class CustomQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def manager_and_queryset_method(self):
        return

class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = models.Manager.from_queryset(CustomQuerySet)()
```

Now you can do:

```
MyModel.objects.manager_and_queryset_method()
```

as well as

```
MyModel.objects.filter(something="else").manager_and_queryset_method()
```

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Although, I know how to make a custom manager from a queryset, but the problem here is that I can't override the model's manager, as it can already be a custom manager that has a custom queryset. I just want to add a custom method to the queryset returned by `get_queryset` of the model's manager.